# Is it possible to use IF statement in hive sql to determine which JOIN statement to use?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to use previous select result to determine which join statement to use, like this:

```
select a.a1,
    b.b1,
    c.c3
from table_a a
left join table_b b
on a.a_join_column = b.b_join_column
if (b.b1 = 1,
    left join (
        select c1 as c_join_column, c3
        from table_c
        where c4 is null
    ) c
    on a.tid = d.tid,
    left join (
        select c2 as c_join_column, c3
        from table_c
        where c4 is not null
    ) c
    on a.a_join_column = c.c_join_column,
)
```

but when I execute this sql, it says something like

```
FAILED: ParseException line 7:0 cannot recognize input near 'if' '(' 'hit_type' in expression specification
```

If it's against the sql gramma, how to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a side note: I see that you are only using outer joins. Is this on purpose or just a bad habit? Only use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` when you purposely want to outer join the table, otherwise use a mere `[INNER] JOIN`.

Comment: "How to achieve my goal".  All I see is syntactically incorrect code.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would all *explain* your goal so your question could be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put all the conditions in the `ON` clause. Use `AND`, `OR`, and parentheses to get the join conditions right.

```
select a.a1, b.b1, c.c3
from table_a a
left join table_b b on a.a_join_column = b.b_join_column
left join table_c c on b.b1 = 1
                    and
                    (
                      (c.c1 = a.a_join_column and c.c4 is null)
                      or 
                      (c.c2 = a.a_join_column and c.c4 is not null)
                    )
```

**UPDATE:** You had tagged your request both with MySQL and Hive. But you are not using MySQL and you say that Hive doesn't support `OR` in join conditions. In that case split the query in two parts the results of which you glue together with `UNION ALL`:

```
select a.a1, b.b1, c.c3
from table_a a
left join table_b b on a.a_join_column = b.b_join_column
left join table_c c on b.b1 = 1 and c.c1 = a.a_join_column and c.c4 is null
union all
select a.a1, b.b1, c.c3
from table_a a
left join table_b b on a.a_join_column = b.b_join_column
left join table_c c on b.b1 = 1 and c.c2 = a.a_join_column and c.c4 is not null
```

Comment: sadly hive sql currently do not support OR in join on condition

Comment: Then make this two separate queries the results of which you glue together with `UNION ALL`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: And why have you tagged your request with MySQL, when you are not using it? I've removed it from the tags now to avoid confusion.